# The space of bounded linear map from $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ to $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ is not separable.

Tags: operator-theory, lp-spaces, separable-spaces

I found an article arguing that the space of bounded linear maps $E=\mathcal{L}(U,U)$ is not separable where $U=L^2(\mathbb{R})$. The argument goes as follows.

> Consider the isometry bounded linear maps $T(s)\in E$ defined by $$T(y)f(x)=f(x+y) \hspace{1cm}\forall x,y\in \mathbb{R} \hspace{5mm} \forall f\in L^2(\mathbb{R}).$$
>
> Then for arbitrary $y,z\in \mathbb{R}$  with $z<y$, we get
> $$\|(T(y)-T(z))f\|_2=\|T(z)[T(y-z)f-f]\|_2=\|T(y-z)f-f\|_2$$
> where the second equality is due to isometry of $T$.  Now, if $supp(f)\subset \left(\frac{z-y}{2},\frac{y-z}{2}  \right)$, then $f$ and $T(y-z)f$ have different support so we get $$\|T(y-z)f-f\|_2^2=2\|f\|_2^2$$ which implies that $$\|T(y)-T(z)\|\geq \sqrt{2} \hspace{1cm}\forall y,z\in \mathbb{R}.$$
> where the last norm is operator norm. Thus, **'$E$ is not separable.'**

**My question** is how we can conclude that $E$ is not separable from the last inequality. I guess it should not require big theorem so I was tackling this with the definition 'a set is separable if there is a countable dense subset' but cannot come up with anything helpful. The point is the family $\{T(x)\}_{x\in \mathbb{R}}$ is just one uncountable family and it is possible that there exists countable subset out side of the family. I hope to have any help from here. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $T\in\mathcal L(U,U)$, $\varepsilon>0$, write 
$$B(T,\varepsilon)=\{S\in\mathcal L(U,U):\|T-S\|<\varepsilon\}.$$
Then the collection 
$$\{B(T(x),\sqrt 2/2):x\in\mathbb R\}$$
is an uncountable collection of (pairwise) disjoint open subsets of $\mathcal L(U,U)$, which cannot happen in a separable space.

Comment: Thank you for your answer (+1)  Could I get more details for why separable space cannot have a collection of uncountable disjoint sets? It seems intuitively trivial but I cannot see the way to prove.

Comment: Sure thing.  Suppose $X$ is a metric space with countable dense set $\{x_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$, and $\{U_\alpha\}_{\alpha\in A}$ is an uncountable collection of disjoint open subsets of $X$.  For each $\alpha$, by density there is some $n(\alpha)\in\mathbb N$ such that $x_{n(\alpha)}\in U_\alpha$.  Thus we obtain a map $n:A\to\mathbb N$.  Since the $U_\alpha$ are disjoint, the map $n$ must be injective, which is impossible.

Comment: Ah! That is clear. Thank you

Comment: You're welcome.  Glad to help!